# Google maps iframe on commercial application

Tags: google-maps, iframe, licensing, bing-maps

I know that for a commercial or private application if I want to use the API of google or bing I have to pay for the service of the API, but this apply to if I only want to use the iframe snipet obtained from the web page of google or bing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with *how* the map is presented on a page (in an iframe, as a static image, in an embed tag is irrelevant) - it's all to do with *what* content is presented, and *who* can access that content.

You can find the terms of use for each, here:

- Bing Maps: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html
- Google Maps: http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html and http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

Google terms state (9.1) a requirement of "*Free, Public Accessibility to Your Maps API Implementation*". So, it cannot be hosted on an intranet, or require a membership to get to the page hosting the map etc.

(Not directly related to your question, but you might also want to note Google term 11.1: "*...By submitting, posting or displaying Your Content in the Service, you give Google a perpetual, irrevocable, worldwide, royalty-free, and non-exclusive license to reproduce, adapt, modify, translate, publicly perform, publicly display and distribute Your Content through the Service....*" - this is the reason why the Ordnance Survey of Great Britain refuse to have their Mastermap data shown on a Google Map (try googling, or see http://www.dailymail.co.uk/money/article-1323119/Google-maps-master-plan-halted-Ordnance-Survey.html for more background info)

The Bing Maps requirement is similar, though more relaxed. "*Your Application and content in your Application must be available publicly without restriction (for example, login or password must not be required) or available internally for free instructional and non-commercial research use.*"

You could try contacting the organisations, though I doubt you'll get a response, and the terms are really quite clear.

Comment: So I guess that as you say, even if I use the javascript api, the static maps api or just the web aplication of google I'm still using some sort of service from google so it apply the same terms of licence of all the services

Comment: Certainly across all its map services, yes.